# How do I delete multiline comment with @author

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I need to delete multiline comment with @author from all the java files.
These comments are added by IDE and are in this format:

```
/**
 *
 * @author AuthorName
 */
```

I used sed and deleted the pattern and the next line using this command:

```
find . -name *.java | xargs sed -i '/@author AuthorName/,+1d'
```

But not sure how I can delete the pattern with previous 2 lines and the next line.

Comment: You just want to replace the line `* @author AuthorName` or the whole comment?

Comment: @hek2mgl I want to delete all those 4 lines..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `gnu sed` you can use `-z` option to treat input delimited by NUL character and use:

```
find . -name '*.java' -exec sed -i -zE \
's~/\*\*[*[:space:]]+\* @author [^\n]*[*[:space:]]+*/\n*~~g' {} +
```

Regex pattern `\*\*[*[:space:]]+\* @author [^\n]*[*[:space:]]+*/\n*` will match a commented block that has `* @author` in the commented text.